# $resource inside in Controller function

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue when putting $resource request inside of Controller function. It works directly from the controller, but doesn't inside the function.

Maybe someone know why? Thanks!

```
angular.module('Vote', ['ngResource']);
    function VotesController($scope, $resource) {
        $scope.simple = $resource('url'); // works
        $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
        $scope.upvoteQuestion = function($scope, $resource) {
            $scope.simple = $resource('url'); // gets error: undefined
            $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define your function `upvoteQuestion` means that it takes 2 arguments (`$scope` and `$resource`). You need to remove that:

```
angular.module('Vote', ['ngResource']);
    function VotesController($scope, $resource) {
        $scope.simple = $resource('url'); // works
        $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
        $scope.upvoteQuestion = function() {
            $scope.simple = $resource('url'); // gets error: undefined
            $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
        };
    }
```

It's a scope problem.
If you define your function with those arguments but don't actually give them when you call the function they'll be set as `undefined` and  that's why you get that error.
If you declare the function without those arguments, as they're not set in the function, it will look for them in the parent scope (the Controller scope) and then find them.